# Converting my deprecated mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm a beginner here I need to learn the basic in converting from `mysql` to `mysqli`. I want to start in configuration first. I have used this connect.php and it's working now I wanted to switch to undeprecated `mysqli`. Please advise me how to modify this script.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "nopassword";
$dbname = "student";

$link_id = mysql_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
if(!$link_id){
    die(mysql_error("Can`t Connect To database")); 
}
else{
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link_id);
}     
if(!$db){
    die(mysql_error("Can`t select database")); 
}     
return;
```

?>

Comment: Please show what your have tried and what isn't working.

Comment: First, change your headline... converting a to a is not the same as converting a to b. Second thing is, use google and search for some tutorials. Actually you dont even need a tutorial. Its a simple connect.

Comment: `<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'nopassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'student');
$link_id = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>` _this is what so far i have modified but i was lost how to modify the if_else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comment....

you could do it that way

```
$host       = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "nopassword";
$dbname     = "student";

$link = mysqli_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$query   = "SELECT knowhow FROM google WHERE myknowhow='leaks'";
$knowhow = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

this is just the simplest way you can do it.

**But you should use it like this (OOP)**

```
$db      = new mysqli($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$knowhow = $db->query("SELECT knowhow FROM google WHERE myknowhow='leaks'");
```

According to your comment:

You dont need the IF/ELSE statements anymore. All errors are catched with

```
die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

In the oop, errors are catched in

```
... new mysqli($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
```

**EDIT**

Since you where blocked asking new questions ill just update this answere:

```
$link    = mysqli_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$query   = "SELECT * FROM student_information where student_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'";
$knowhow = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$data    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);     
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

$i = 0;     
while($i < $numRows){
    echo $data[$i++] . "<br />";
}

// I would not use a while in this case. I would prefere a foreach
// just to prevent from using a endless loop and 1 row less code :)

foreach($data as $d){
    echo $d . "<br />";
}
```

### Please use MySqli as a Class like $db = new Mysqli();

Comment: Wow that's the best working clue i ever received. Thank you very much, it really works and of course i choose the simplest way that you suggested (not the OOP). But seems i got a new problem here in other page. Again i need your help to convert this to my_sqli `include_once 'Connect.php';
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_information where student_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'",$link_id);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $numRows = mysql_numrows($result);
 $i = 0;
 while($i < $numRows){` Another please :-)

Comment: accept this answere, may vote it up and ask a new question for this.

Comment: Thanks for that reminder. Apology for im still new in stack overflow. I already accept it but i cant still vote up for now due to reputation issues. I'll make another thread for this new question of mine if im still be allowed to ask question by s.o

Comment: You will allways be allowed to ask questions. And its notz an issue, its just because you have to gether experience in SOF to do that. :)

Comment: i am banned to ask new questions for now. :-(

Comment: @and. On this moment im applying it 75% of my webapages and still working on it fully. Im still running it on xammp for now, hope there will be no changes when i upload it on the net. One more thing, what do you mean when you said "Please use MySqli as a Class like $db = new Mysqli();" i am interested to apply it also maybe it can be used to make my site more secure.

Comment: with this i mean you to create an object like: `$db = new Mysqli();` and than you would work with the created object like `$db->query("SELECT * FROM FOO");`